# AuthenticationManager does not contain a definition for GetAzureADAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, authentication, pnp, azure

I'm running into some trouble when trying to get a client context from PnP for an Azure AD app only connection.

I'm trying to follow [This tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread) on how to create an application that would run on a SharePoint tenant with `DisableCustomAppAuthentication` on.

Unfortunately I fall short when it comes to retrieving the client context from Azure in c#. Exactly at this point:

```
public class CustomAuth
{
    public static ClientContext GetContextObject(string siteUrl)
    {
        string _clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];
        string _clientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecret"];
        var authManager = new AuthenticationManager("********-b7a4-4d80-8254-920df9b5df4e", "c:\\dev\\cert.pfx", "******", "mytenant.sharepoint.com");
        var context = authManager.GetAzureADAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext(siteUrl);


        context.Load(context.Web, p => p.Title);



        try
        {
            context.ExecuteQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }



        return context;
    }
}
```

It seems that the authentication manager does not contain the GetAzureAd function. I tried with GetContext instead, but it just loads indefinitely.

I'm on .net 4.7.2 , the NuGet for PNP.Framework is on 1.10 and PnPCore is on 1.7.90. Do I need to upgrade .net for it to work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [PnP Framework GitHub page](https://github.com/pnp/pnpframework),

> PnP Framework is a .NET Standard 2.0 / .NET 5.0 / .NET 6.0 library targeting Microsoft 365 containing the PnP Provisioning engine

Try using these:

- .NET 5.0 or .NET 6.0
- [PnP Framework NuGet v1.10.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PnP.Framework/) - Check [Dependencies](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PnP.Framework/#dependencies-body-tab) as well
- PnP.Core (>= 1.7.0)